# plt graphic test and train accuracy doesnt see

Tags: python, machine-learning, graphics, spyder, resnet

I couldn’t visualize the test and train data on the graph plane in any way. My test, train, and loss values are clear, but I can’t draw a suitable graph for them. I shared the image below. Can you please help me?

I also added the code I wrote below.

```
#%% Saving Training Model

torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'trained_model.pth')
print("Trained model saved.")
#%%
print("Loss list: ", loss_list)
print("Test accuracy: ", test_acc)
print("Train accuracy: ", train_acc)

#%% visualize
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(loss_list, label="Loss", color="black")
ax1.set_xlabel('Epoch')
ax1.set_ylabel('Loss')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(range(len(test_acc)), np.array(test_acc) / 100, label="Test Acc", color="red")
ax2.plot(range(len(train_acc)), np.array(train_acc) / 100, label="Train Acc", color="blue")
ax2.set_ylabel('Accuracy')

ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.title("Loss vs Test Accuracy")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#save figure 
plt.savefig('resultus_LSIFIR.PNG')
print("Training Results Saved.")
            
#%% Load Model if You Want 

loaded_model = Net()
loaded_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('trained_model.pth'))
print("Trained Model Loaded")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaHw8.jpg

Comment: seems that your accuracy have only a few points (less than 1k) could you show the `len` of `test_acc` , `train_acc` and `loss_list` ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaHw8.jpg

here this graphic

Comment: I think I need to retrain the model to be able to show the dimensions of the loss list, train accuracy, and test accuracy, even though I have saved the model. Is that correct?

Comment: yep, the output of the model is not in the model parameters. you could save those results in every iteration in the rerun.